# How portable is using the low bit of a pointer as a flag?

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization, portability

If there is for example a class that requires a pointer and a `bool`. For simplicity an `int` pointer will be used in examples, but the pointer type is irrelevant as long as it points to something whose `size()` is more than 1 .

Defining the class with `{ bool , int *}` data members will result in the class having a size that is double the size of the pointer and a lot of wasted space

If the pointer does not point to a `char` (or other data of `size(1)`), then presumably the low bit will always be zero.  The class could defined with `{int *}` or for convenience: `union { int *, uintptr_t }`

The `bool` is implemented by setting/clearing the low bit of the pointer as per the logical `bool` value and clearing the bit when you need to use the pointer.

The defined way:

```
struct myData
{
 int * ptr;
 bool flag;
};
myData x;

// initialize
x.ptr = new int;
x.flag = false;

// set flag true
x.flag = true;

// set flag false
x.flag = false;

// use ptr
*(x.ptr)=7;

// change ptr
x = y;                // y is another int *
```

And the proposed way:

```
union tiny
{
 int * ptr;
 uintptr_t flag;
};
tiny x;

// initialize
x.ptr = new int;

// set flag true
x.flag |= 1;

// set flag false
x.flag &= ~1;

// use ptr
tiny clean=x;      // note that clean will likely be optimized out
clean.flag &= ~1;  // back to original value as assigned to ptr
*(clean.ptr)=7;

// change ptr
bool flag=x.flag;
x.ptr = y;             // y is another int *
x.flag |= flag;
```

This seems to be undefined behavior, but how portable is this?

Comment: The slow down would from changing the bit back and forth is probably more trouble than its worth, have you checked to make sure it actually runs faster

Comment: @aaronman - it is significantly faster, hence the question

Comment: what's your mean of Defining the class as a bool?

Comment: @DarkHorse it read as a bool and a pointer - clarifications in last edit should help

Comment: Just for reference (and further searches): the concept is known as [tagged pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer)

Comment: LLVM actually uses the lower 3 bits to store flags in their codebase (extensively). But I don't know LLVM well enough to say that they are doing this because this is very portable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as you restore the pointer's low-order bit before trying to use it as a pointer, it's *likely* to be "reasonably" portable, as long as your system, your C++ implementation, and  your code meet certain assumptions.

I can't necessarily give you a complete list of assumptions, but off the top of my head:

- It assumes you're not pointing to anything whose size is 1 byte. This excludes `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `int8_t`, and `uint8_t`. (And that assumes `CHAR_BIT == 8`; on exotic systems with, say, 16-bit or 32-bit bytes, other types might be excluded.)
- It assumes objects whose size is at least 2 bytes are always aligned at an even address. Note that x86 doesn't *require* this; you can access a 4-byte `int` at an odd address, but it will be slightly slower. But compilers typically arrange for objects to be stored at even addresses. Other architectures may have different requirements.
- It assumes a pointer to an even address has its low-order bit set to 0.

For that last assumption, I actually have a concrete counterexample. On Cray vector systems (J90, T90, and SV1 are the ones I've used myself) a machine address points to a 64-bit word, but the C compiler under Unicos sets `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Byte pointers are implemented in software, with the 3-bit byte offset within a word stored in the otherwise unused *high-order* 3 bits of the 64-bit pointer. So a pointer to an 8-byte aligned object could have easily its low-order bit set to 1.

There have been Lisp implementations ([example](http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/8.2/doc/operators/system/memref.htm)) that use the low-order 2 bits of pointers to store a type tag. I vaguely recall this causing serious problems during porting.

Bottom line: You can *probably* get away with it for most systems. Future architectures are largely unpredictable, and I can easily imagine your scheme breaking on the next Big New Thing.

Some things to consider:

Can you store the boolean values in a bit vector *outside* your class? (Maintaining the association between your pointer and the corresponding bit in the bit vector is left as an exercise).

Consider adding code to all pointer operations that fails with an error message if it ever sees a pointer with its low-order bit set to 1. Use `#ifdef` to remove the checking code in your production version. If you start running into problems on some platform, build a version of your code with the checks enabled and see what happens.

I suspect that, as your application grows (they seldom shrink), you'll want to store more than just a `bool` along with your pointer. If that happens, the space issue goes away, because you're already using that extra space anyway.

Comment: If the structure or union contains any type requiring an alignment more stringent than byte alignment, then the structure as a whole will be aligned on a suitable address. You could only run into problems if every member of the structure is a `char` type of some sort; such a structure does not need to be aligned specially.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes *if* there are any such types. There very probably are, but it's entirely possible for a 2-byte or 4-byte type to require only 1-byte alignment. Not common these days, but permitted by the language.

Comment: That Lisp example was useful; I was thinking of using the LSB of a pointer to store if a cons cell was allocated from a memory pool for a Lisp implementation. Might not be as portable as I first thought. Should not work on Cray (as you said) nor on AVR/Arduino systems.

Answer (score 4):

In "theory": it's undefined behavior as far as I know.

In "reality": it'll work on everyday x86/x64 machines, and probably ARM too?
I can't really make a statement beyond that.

Comment: bit operations that change the pointer value and then restore them seem to be standard.   Whether non narrow character types have an align > 1 seems to be where it gets into implementation specific

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Yep, alignment is implementation specific, that's the "theory" part of the answer.  Practically though, most compilers align pointers for performance reasons.  Even if a CPU architecture doesn't allow for unaligned accesses, there's nothing stopping the compiler from generating/using pointer values that are unaligned. eg. See gcc's --munaligned-access.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: The trouble isn't just the alignment, it's the fact that the language doesn't allow you to treat pointers as integers. So if you do that, it's technically undefined behavior as far as "standard C++" is concerned --- so unless your compiler makes extra guarantees (which it might), the code isn't standard C++ and therefore isn't guaranteed to behave correctly.

Comment: In theory, you have to go through some fairly convoluted set of casts (`uintptr_t` is one of them) to convert the pointer to a manipulable integer, and then do the bit flipping or testing, and the conversions back again. I'm surprised it is quicker than doing the job the regular way, though not completely since half as much data means you get better cache locality.

Comment: @Mehrdad - it seems that as long as you take a pointer - convert it tto an integral type of at least the size of the pointer - do something - undo it - and then convert it back to pointer - its okay: `the result of an additive or **bitwise** operation, one of whose operands is an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value P, if that result converted by reinterpret_cast<void*> would compare equal to a safely-derived pointer computable from reinterpret_cast<void*>(P).`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - basically its just an extra & before using the pointer - all the casting is free.  Testing the lowbit is as expesive as using a bool.  But you nailed it, its about avoiding cache misses.  So a (generally) one clock cycle operation is a small price to pay to avoid a many cycle cache miss.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: That sentence has a big ***if*** inside it. There's no guarantee that that condition holds true in implementations, is there?

Comment: @Mehrdad not in this case - as long as `alignof > 1` then it is guaranteed to work.  Casting back and forth are noops. setting an **unset** bit and then unsetting it is a noop. The sticky part is making sure the **unset** bit is indeed unset and that is predicated on `alignof > 1` being true

Comment: @Mehrdad - thats not whats happening.  The pointer is converted to an integral. the integral is manupulated and then restored to its **original** value, and then converted back to a pointer.  This is guarenteed to result in the **original** pointer value being restored.

Comment: @Glenn: Sorry I deleted my last comment because it was confusing. I meant that I don't think you can assume that the address space is linear in the integer representation. What if the bits are reversed, for example? Then the "unused" bit is at the top, not the bottom.

Comment: Actually it probably won't work on ARM (at least not for function pointers because the LSB of a code pointer in the arm architecture represents ARM or THUMB mode code)

Answer (score 3):

It's very portable, and furthermore, you can `assert` when you accept the raw pointer to make sure it meets the alignment requirement. This will insure against the unfathomable future compiler that somehow messes you up.

Only reasons not to do it are the readability cost and general maintenance associated with "hacky" stuff like that. I'd shy away from it unless there's a clear gain to be made. But it is sometimes totally worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Conform to those rules and it should be very portable.