# Read low pointer bit in way that could *probably* work on as many systems as possible

Tags: c, pointers, c89, termination, type-punning

It seems that the low bit of pointers being 0 is more-or-less pretty portable *(where portable obviously does not mean "standard", but that people get away with it and can use it to some advantage in some cases, hopefully disable-able with a compile switch)*.

Projects that want to get fiddly have used it, with less luck on the second lowest bit:

[How portable is using the low bit of a pointer as a flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991506/how-portable-is-using-the-low-bit-of-a-pointer-as-a-flag)

But let's say one doesn't want to just poke a bit of data or not into a pointer of a known type.  What you wish you could do instead is to use that low bit being 0 to allow a pointer type to do "double-duty" as a terminator.

So your items look like this:

```
struct Item {
    uintptr_t flags; // low bit zero means "not an item"
    type1 field1;
    type2 field2;
    ...
};
```

Then you'd like to have a situation where some container of items looks like this:

```
[(flags field1 field2...) (flags field1 field2...) some-pointer stuff stuff...]
```

You'd be thus getting away with a "sunk-cost" (let's say some internal management pointer in the data structure for another purpose) doing your termination for you.

---

**UPDATE:** To be clearer on the situation: this is where one controls the codebase and structures.  So any pointer in a structure used like this you could declare as a union type, for instance:

```
union Maybe_Terminator_Pointer {
    uintptr_t flags;
    type1* pointer1;
    type2* pointer2;
    ...
};
```

...and then use that, if it helps.  Excluding `char*`s is fine, as they of course would not count.

---

So an extra type punning problem here is: the pointer being used to do the test-for-termination is an `Item*`, and the routine doing the checking doesn't know which sort of pointer `some-pointer` is specifically.

I'm wondering what--if any--is the best gamble is for being able to port and compile such a trick.  That includes turning the pointers into unions, #ifdef'ing the endianness of the machine and getting a char* from the byte with the bit, etc.  Whatever might be *more* likely to work, if anyone has experience or guesses.

Imagine it's worth the effort for your case, shaving off a large amount of data.  And you have the backup scenario of if people compiling find the trick isn't working somewhere...an #ifdef could use full-sized items for terminators and waste the extra space.  So wondering if there are any tips on to make this obviously-standards-violating trick have a better chance of working on more systems.

Comment: There is no "least non-portable" way. And architectures which don't require alignment or if you used `packed` `struct`s the LSB is not available at all. Unless you have **real** memory constraints, the additonal code overhead is not worth the hassle. And if you have memory issues, you have a specific system anyway. Still that is fart beyond the C standard.

Comment: @Olaf I don't know if you're saying in particular that this case is a significantly less potentially possible thing than in the linked post or not... e.g. the quote *"In 'theory': it's undefined behavior as far as I know.  In 'reality': it'll work on everyday x86/x64 machines, and probably ARM too?"*  My question is more about the "reality" aspect; especially as this is something that could (as I say) just be turned off in a compile if the specifics of the environment weren't working out, so how to be on the least-bad-side of the compiler if writing this (best odds, essentially)

Comment: I stated scenarios it does not work, including x86 and ARM. On 8 bit architectures it will fail epically.

Comment: Not more than on widewr architectures. But that is a completely unrelated subject.

Comment: The goal to allow "*any* pointer type" to be abused this way is extremely unrealistic.  Most architectures use *all* pointer bits for `char` pointers, for instance.  So at the very least, you would only be able to do this for pointers to data types whose addresses guarantee a 0 low-order bit, and that will not be portable.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah yes char*, edited that in as not a requirement.  Also not a requirement to really be "any" pointer type, so I edited that too...there are only some small number of structures which would be doing this, but more than one...so the Item doesn't know which specific kind of other-written pointer it would be hitting.  It's obviously "not portable" in the sense of "not standard" but I've clarified that I'm just looking to see if there's a technique empirically likely to work across more platforms if offering the feature as a build option people could try.

Comment: Assuming you only use a pointed-to type that has a certain alignment requirement, this is portable *iff* the system uses a natural mapping of `uintptr_t` to pointers (which it is supposed to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Self-answering to provide more information and allow people to spot any potential problems with my alternative.)*

> So wondering if there are any tips on to make this obviously-standards-violating trick have a better chance of working on more systems.

---

Tip One (as per comments) is don't do this if you can possibly find another way.

For example, "you" mention this layout:

> ```
> [(flags field1 field2...) (flags field1 field2...) some-pointer stuff stuff...]
> ```

But is there anything in "`stuff stuff`" that *isn't* a pointer--perhaps boring old integers that are known to be even--where you could do the same trick?  If so, why not reorder this like:

> ```
> [(flags field1 field2...) (flags field1 field2...) even-uintptr_t stuff...]
> ```

That way when you read `flags` from either in an `Item` or not, it will be the same type.  If you look around at things that aren't opaque like pointers, you might find obvious non-opaque numbers in the current code that are always even...for instance, a lot of byte counts measuring aggregates are things you likely are guaranteed to have as `% 2 = 0`.

---

Tip Two applies to the above alternative--and perhaps helps the odds with the standards-breaking-pointer-version too.  Be sure that when you write the value you go through an "aliasing" pointer, and do not write the field directly via `.` or `->`.

There is no requirement for the compiler to ensure memory coherence between two different structures on a field, just because they are the same type.  Say `struct A` begins with an `uintptr_t field_a` and `struct B` begins with an `uintptr_t field_b`, and you put a pointer to both at the same address.  If you do `some_a->field_a = value;`, then reading back from a `some_b->field_b` pointer at that address might well not see that update, because the compiler doesn't expect you to be writing B fields via an A pointer.

Hence go through a pointer to do the write.  Something like `uintptr_t  *alias = &some_a->field_a;` and then `*alias = value` will enforce coherence with the successive reads of any integer **(!)**.  *(Dissatisfaction with the performance consequences of this property of pointers [is why `restrict` exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict).  If this trick is to work, it can only do so by exploiting the non-restrict behavior of pointers.)*

**(!)** - I think you only have to do the write through a pointer, and not the reads, but perhaps someone can provide insight.